# Stop WooCommerce Subscription Admin Renewal Notifications for $0 Value Products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I found the following plugin that stops sending notifications to customers when a $0 value subscription renews. This is working perfectly fine for customers but the admin still receives notificaitons. Would it be possible to amend the code to eliminate sending renewal emails to admin too?

Appreciate your help

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WooCommerce Subscriptions No $0 Emails
Plugin URI:
Description: Do not send processing or completed renewal order emails to customers when the order or renewal is for $0.00.
Author:
Author URI:
Version: 0.1
*/
 
function eg_maybe_remove_email( $order_id ){

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    if ( 0 == $order->get_total() ) {

        switch( current_filter() ) {
            case 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_renewal_notification':
                $email_class = 'WCS_Email_Completed_Renewal_Order';
                break;
            case 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_renewal_notification':
                $email_class = 'WCS_Email_Processing_Renewal_Order';
                break;
            case 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_renewal_notification':
                $email_class = 'WCS_Email_Customer_Renewal_Invoice';
                break;
            default:
                $email_class = '';
                break;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $email_class ) ) {
            remove_action( current_filter(), array( WC()->mailer()->emails[ $email_class ], 'trigger' ) );
        }
    }
    
    if ( 0 == $order->get_total() ) {

        switch( current_filter() ) {
            case 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_renewal_notification':
                $email_class = 'WCS_Email_New_Renewal_Order';
                break;
            default:
                $email_class = '';
                break;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $email_class ) ) {
            remove_action( current_filter(), array( WC()->mailer()->emails[ $email_class ], 'trigger' ) );
        }
    }   

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_renewal_notification', 'eg_maybe_remove_email', 0, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_renewal_notification', 'eg_maybe_remove_email', 0, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_renewal_notification', 'eg_maybe_remove_email', 0, 1 );
```

Answer (score 2):

These are the below email class that is used in WooCommerce Subscription.

```
$email_classes['WCS_Email_New_Renewal_Order']              = new WCS_Email_New_Renewal_Order();
$email_classes['WCS_Email_New_Switch_Order']               = new WCS_Email_New_Switch_Order();
$email_classes['WCS_Email_Processing_Renewal_Order']       = new WCS_Email_Processing_Renewal_Order();
$email_classes['WCS_Email_Completed_Renewal_Order']        = new WCS_Email_Completed_Renewal_Order();
$email_classes['WCS_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Renewal_Order'] = new WCS_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Renewal_Order();
$email_classes['WCS_Email_Completed_Switch_Order']         = new WCS_Email_Completed_Switch_Order();
$email_classes['WCS_Email_Customer_Renewal_Invoice']       = new WCS_Email_Customer_Renewal_Invoice();
$email_classes['WCS_Email_Cancelled_Subscription']         = new WCS_Email_Cancelled_Subscription();
$email_classes['WCS_Email_Expired_Subscription']           = new WCS_Email_Expired_Subscription();
$email_classes['WCS_Email_On_Hold_Subscription']           = new WCS_Email_On_Hold_Subscription();
```

`WCS_Email_New_Switch_Order` and `WCS_Email_New_Switch_Order` these are the only class that is sending email to admin.

Below are actions that are used in `WCS_Email_New_Switch_Order` and `WCS_Email_New_Switch_Order` to send emails.

```
'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_renewal_notification'
'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_completed_renewal_notification'
'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_renewal_notification'
'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing_renewal_notification'
'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_completed_renewal_notification'
'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_on-hold_renewal_notification'
'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_processing_renewal_notification'
'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_completed_renewal_notification'
'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_on-hold_renewal_notification'
'woocommerce_subscriptions_switch_completed_switch_notification'
```

So you have to also add this above action with your callback function `eg_maybe_remove_email`. check below code.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: WooCommerce Subscriptions No $0 Emails
Plugin URI:
Description: Do not send a processing or completed renewal order emails to customers when the order or renewal is for $0.00.
Author:
Author URI:
Version: 0.1
*/

function eg_maybe_remove_email( $order_id ){

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    if ( 0 == $order->get_total() ) {

        $email_class = array();
        
        switch( current_filter() ) {
            case 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_renewal_notification':
                $email_class[] = 'WCS_Email_Completed_Renewal_Order';
                break;
            case 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_renewal_notification':
                $email_class[] = 'WCS_Email_Processing_Renewal_Order';
                $email_class[] = 'WCS_Email_New_Renewal_Order';
                break;
            case 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_renewal_notification':
                $email_class[] = 'WCS_Email_Customer_Renewal_Invoice';
                $email_class[] = 'WCS_Email_New_Renewal_Order';
                break;
            case 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_completed_renewal_notification':
            case 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_renewal_notification':
            case 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing_renewal_notification':
            case 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_completed_renewal_notification':
            case 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_on-hold_renewal_notification':
            case 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_processing_renewal_notification':
            case 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_completed_renewal_notification':
            case 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_on-hold_renewal_notification':
                $email_class[] = 'WCS_Email_New_Renewal_Order';
                break;
            case 'woocommerce_subscriptions_switch_completed_switch_notification':
                $email_class[] = 'WCS_Email_New_Switch_Order';
                break;
            default:
                $email_class[] = array();
                break;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $email_class ) ) {
            foreach ( $email_class  as $key => $email ) {
                remove_action( current_filter(), array( WC()->mailer()->emails[ $email ], 'trigger' ) );
            }
        }

    }
    
}

//customer
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_renewal_notification',             'eg_maybe_remove_email', 0, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_processing_renewal_notification', 'eg_maybe_remove_email', 0, 1 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_renewal_notification',                'eg_maybe_remove_email', 0, 1 );

//admin
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_completed_renewal_notification',    'eg_maybe_remove_email', 0, 1  );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_pending_to_on-hold_renewal_notification',      'eg_maybe_remove_email', 0, 1  );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_processing_renewal_notification',    'eg_maybe_remove_email', 0, 1  );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_completed_renewal_notification',     'eg_maybe_remove_email', 0, 1  );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_failed_to_on-hold_renewal_notification',       'eg_maybe_remove_email', 0, 1  );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_processing_renewal_notification', 'eg_maybe_remove_email', 0, 1  );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_completed_renewal_notification',  'eg_maybe_remove_email', 0, 1  );
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_cancelled_to_on-hold_renewal_notification',    'eg_maybe_remove_email', 0, 1  );
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscriptions_switch_completed_switch_notification',        'eg_maybe_remove_email', 0, 1  );
```